# Most efficient way to select (& store) rows from DB that contain a certain char in a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

**Given:** objects with string attribute X should be stored in DB (MSSQL)
**Important:** string attribute is built from approx 0-30 different chars. I.e. these chars are from a defined char pool (that contains those 30 elements).

E.g. pool (stable!) is: "A,N,H,J,K,L". Object X1 has "ANHL", object X2 has "JHK", object X2 has "N"...

**Problem:** application must select all objects with e.g. X.*contains*('N'). This will be **always only one char**!

**Question:** How can these objects be stored and/or selected efficiently? I.e. storing as plain nvarchar field and selecting via "like '%N%' is not an option!

Comment: How about using substring instead of LIKE? Although your question still little bit vague for me.

Comment: I don't think that substring() is a lot more efficient than like...

Comment: The easiest way is to install the Full-Text Search option and then define a Full-Text Index on that Table/Column.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Nope. Full-Text won't help you with this problem. It searches for words not for characters in words.

Comment: @TToni All you do is add a column that has a trigger to put a space between every character.  Its pretty easy.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: You would also have to disable the stopword list which might compromise other tables with full text indexes. Also you only get asynchronous updates of the index, which might not be sufficient. In any case I doubt this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: @TToni I said "easiest", not "most efficient".

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Well, efficiency is what the OP asked for. But my main point would be that you try to use a feature in a way it wasn't designed for. Sometimes that works, sometimes it can even lead to great new ideas, but in general it will just give you endless trouble.

Comment: I still think Full-Text Search is an option since we can save the characters space-separated. And since we have only a restricted char pool size this seems from the present view the most efficient concept. But I don't know how good this MSSQL feature is in reality.

Comment: **Update:** After tests with a table with 10.000.000 the full-text index performs very good. But it decreases as more PK-fields are used in the select up to a certain threshold where a simple "like" even outperforms it. Conclusion: Use full-text indices especially (only?) if you don't have further limiting criteria.

Answer (score 1):

For each character in the set create a column of the type "BIT SPARSE" and create a filtered nonclustered index for each column (with the filter set to "NOT NULL" for the column of course).

You will want to make your clustered index key as small as possible for this kind of setup.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a very common (frequently executed) sql statement, where the performance id extremely important, and the 1-char value N you are looking for is constant, I'd create an indexed view, or put an [Index on a persisted computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You can create  a computed column that returns a Boolean 1/0 depending on whether that character is in the string attribute.

```
Alter table myTable
   Add Column HasA As
     (case CharIndex('A', stringAttribute) 
             When 0 Then 0 Else 1 End)
      Persisted
```

If the value of N is not constant, but is limited to one of a small number of values, you could create one persisted computed column for each value that N might be, with an index on each one.

Comment: Not bad, but you want to make this a SPARSE column and use a filtered Index.

Comment: Thought already about this. But you would have to do this for every char from the pool which would not really be manageable. In this case one could also just add a real column for every char and use those.

Comment: @Strinder: Why would it be unmanageable? As long as the character set does not change, you should be fine. Creation of the columns and indexes can be done with a bit of basic scripting.

Comment: @TToni 1st there is an unstream import process that must adopt to it. Which would be a lot of effort. 2nd there is a certain probability that the carachter set will change infrequently.

Answer (score -1):

it's a workaround but should work

```
select *
from Table
where CHARINDEX('N', ColumnName, charindex('N', ColumnName) +1)  = 0
```

it simple checks if there is another 'N' after the first one

in the adventureworks database i did a

```
select *
from Person.Person
where CHARINDEX('N', LastName, charindex('N', LastName) +1) >0
```

to find every person where the lastnames contains more then 1 'N'

if possible i would change the table structure and create a 1:n relationship. the second table would just consist of two columns

```
ObjectId | Attribute
```

so you could get the right objects with a simple join

cheers

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question and anyway I see nothing here that would solve the performance problem.

Comment: with the first select you would get the desired result for the actual problem, might not be fast... in the second part i tried to describe a easy solution where you have to change the table design

Comment: The point regarding performance is that with your approach no index can be used and an index is the key to speed up this whole business, which is what the OP asked for.